# very smooth hash (VSH) Stepwise examples

Tags: hash, collision-resistance

Can someone please point me to or give me stepwise example of VSH hash function. I couldn't find an example or a reference implementation. I tried to go through [original publication](https://eprint.iacr.org/2005/193.pdf) but it seems way too cryptic to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a small example. We'll set $k=8$ so that we can hash messages of up to $2^8-1=255$ bits. We note that the eight smallest primes are $p_1=2, p_2=3$, $p_3=5,\ldots p_8=19$. We'll also pick a "hard to factor" number $n=314159265358979323$ (note that it is not actually necessary to know the factors of $n$).

To hash the 60-bit number $x$ `100110000111101011110010110011111110010111101110000110010100` we divide it into blocks of eight bits: `10011000 01111010 11110010 11001111 11100101 11101110 00011001 0100`; pad the last block with zeros: `10011000 01111010 11110010 11001111 11100101 11101110 00011001 01000000` and add a final block representing the length: `10011000 01111010 11110010 11001111 11100101 11101110 00011001 01000000 00111100`.

The VSH of $x$ is $p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_8^{e_8}\mod n$ where the $e_i$ is constructed by taking the $i$th least significant bit of each block and concatenating. Thus $e_1$ is the leftmost bits of each block $000110100=52$, similarly for $e_2$ we have $011101000=232$, $e_3=57$,
$e_4=429$, $e_5=453$, $e_6=217$, $e_7=250$ and $e_8=376$ and so
$$VSH(x)=2^{52}3^{232}5^{57}7^{429}11^{453}13^{217}17^{250}19^{376}\mod n$$
$$= 200591979525226314$$

Computation of the hash can be made ore efficient and pipelined by what is effectively a use of [Shamir's trick](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007/978-1-4419-5906-5_1157). To do this we start with an initial value 1 mod $n$, then use each block to determine a subset of small primes to multiply our value but, followed by a square of our value. Thus we start $x_0=1$, our first block is `10011000` which selects the primes $p_8, p_5, p_4=19,11,7$ and compute
$$x_1=x_0^2\times(7\times 11\times 19)\mod n=1463$$
the next block is `01111010` which selects the primes 3,7,11,13,17 so that
$$x_2=x_1^2\times(3\times7\times11\times13\times 17)\mod n=109267977819$$
followed by
$$x_3=x_2^2\times(3\times11\times13\times17\times19)\mod n=25314401756605599$$
and
$$x_4=251897391984383465$$
$$x_5=259626239061055217$$
$$x_6=190834175947594433$$
$$x_7=249101195160685902$$
$$x_8=78295427833839690$$
$$x_9=200591979525226314$$
and so on, eventually getting the same answer as above for $x_9$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I believe x is 58 bits and not 60 bits. Did I miss something? Samir's trick seems interesting.

Comment: Apologies, I have appended two zeros to $x$ so that the length is now correct.